# How to search a folder and all of its subfolders for files of a certain type

Tags: ruby, file-io, recursion

I am trying to search for all files of a given type in a given folder and copy them to a new folder.

I need to specify a root folder and search through that folder and all of its subfolders for any files that match the given type.

How do I search the root folder's subfolders and their subfolders? It seems like a recursive method would work, but I cannot implement one correctly.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You want the [Find](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) module. `Find.find` takes a string containing a path, and will pass the parent path along with the path of each file and sub-directory to an accompanying block. Some example code:

```
require 'find'

pdf_file_paths = []
Find.find('path/to/search') do |path|
  pdf_file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\.pdf$/
end
```

That will recursively search a path, and store all file names ending in .pdf in an array.

Answer (score 124):

Try this:

```
Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/*.pdf")
```

which is the same as

```
Dir["#{folder}/**/*.pdf"]
```

Where the folder variable is the path to the root folder you want to search through.

Comment: The approach is right, but the implementation is wrong. It needs to be Dir.glob('**/*.pdf')

Comment: I think the OP wanted recursive, didn't they?

Comment: The original answer (rogerdpack) worked for me, but Jergason's didn't, I'm afraid.

Comment: @rogerdpack As far as I understand, this method is recursive. Answer should actually be `Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/*.pdf")`, where the `folder` variable is the path to the root folder you want to search through.

Comment: This right here is indeed the right answer. e.g. I had the following use case and it worked: Dir.glob("#{ENGINE_ROOT}/lib/data/excel/**/*.{xls,XLS}")

Comment: Also case insensitive by default

Comment: @Konstantin This, or `Dir#[]`, are what I usually use.  However, there is a catch: `Dir.glob` loads all of the paths into memory.  This is usually fine, but if you have a great number of paths, one may prefer to use the Find module instead, since it delivers paths to the block as it finds them.

Comment: I agree with @WayneConrad on this. You can inadvertently halt your program as Ruby allocates enough memory to store a big array. This is very similar to [slurping a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-not-a-good-practice). It's more efficient, and probably faster, to let `Find` process the hierarchy rather than throw it at the OS and potentially get an unexpected array. Debugging that situation is difficult.

Answer (score 28):

If speed is a concern, prefer `Dir.glob` over `Find.find`.

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
           Find.find   124.000  i/100ms
            Dir.glob   515.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
           Find.find      1.242k (± 4.7%) i/s -      6.200k in   5.001398s
            Dir.glob      5.249k (± 4.5%) i/s -     26.265k in   5.014632s

Comparison:
            Dir.glob:     5248.5 i/s
           Find.find:     1242.4 i/s - 4.22x slower
```

```
require 'find'
require 'benchmark/ips'

dir = '.'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report 'Find.find' do
    Find.find(dir).select { |f| f =~ /\*\.pdf/ }
  end

  x.report 'Dir.glob' do
    Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*\.pdf")
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

Using `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: Thank you for the post. It is very helpful for beginners like me to figure out which method should I use among `Dir.glob` vs `Find.find`.

Comment: Find should be slower in this case because you are finding with a regex.  Dir.glob on the other hand, is not as powerful as a regex so I would expect it to be faster.

Comment: I suppose you could use `#end_with?` to compare them a little more closely....

Comment: @hirowatari Regex or not makes no difference - you can replace the whole block content with `false` and it will still be significant slower (give it a try). This is because calling a block also requires some time and happens for every item found, whereas `glob` filters internally and only will return once it is done collecting results. Therefor your filter used with `find` can be as complicated as you like, it could be 100 lines of code with lookups and multiple regexes whereas `glob` just understands one simple pattern per call. If you can express your search that way, prefer `glob`.

Comment: But then if you have to actually do something with these files you will need to be calling something for each of them. So depending on use case comparison may or may not be fair. Also for huge directory trees, one may not want to store the whole array in memory. So sometimes one would be better, another time the other.

Answer (score 13):

As a small improvement to Jergason and Matt's answer above, here's how you can condense to a single line:

```
pdf_file_paths = Find.find('path/to/search').select { |p| /.*\.pdf$/ =~ p }
```

This uses the Find method as above, but leverages the fact that the result is an enumerable (and as such we can use select) to get an array back with the set of matches