# Ruby - Search and collect files in all directorys

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to search for a certain file type within all directories on my unix system using a ruby script. I understand the following code will search all files ending with .pdf within the current directory:

```
my_pdfs = Dir['*pdf']
```

As well as:

```
my_pdfs = Dir.glob('*.pdf').each do |f|
  puts f
end
```

But how about searching **all** directories and sub-directories for files with the .pdf extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching a folder and all of its subfolders for files of a certain type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498539/searching-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-for-files-of-a-certain-type)

Comment: @Matt I actually tried to use the solution there but got the following syntax error: syntax error, unexpected '='
My first assumption was that i was using ruby 1.9.3 and that was posted in 2010 so it was an earlier version of ruby?

Comment: @MurQuirk What line of that did you get the syntax error on? Perhaps you should comment there with your problem with it?

Comment: For those who had problems with the solution on [Searching a folder and all of its subfolders for files of a certain type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498539/searching-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-for-files-of-a-certain-type), on line 5 of the code the tilde goes after the equal operator, not before. So instead of `~=` its `=~`  This probably shouldn't be posted here, but once I get 50 rep points I'll go ahead and comment on it over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `Find` module:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

Using Dir.glob is less than ideal since globbing doesn't handle recursion nearly as well as something like find.

Also if you're on a *nix box try using the `find` command. Its pretty amazingly useful for one liners.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
pdfs=Dir['/**/*.pdf']
```

?

Not using Linux right now, so don't know if that will work. The `**` syntax implies recursive listing.