# Check if there is any file or directory matching pattern using ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to check if pattern with wildcards, e.g. `/var/data/**/*.xml` is matching to any file or directory on the disk.

Obviously I could use `Dir.glob` but it is very slow when there are millions of files because it is too eager - it returns all files matching the pattern while I only need to know if there is any.

Is there any way I could check that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498539/searching-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-for-files-of-a-certain-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby-only

You could use [`Find`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html), [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html#method-c-find) and [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) :D.

I couldn't find any other File/Dir method that returns an Enumerator.

```
require 'find'
Find.find("/var/data/").find{|f| f=~/\.xml$/i }
#=> first xml file found inside "/var/data". nil otherwise
# or
Find.find("/var/data/").find{|f| File.extname(f).downcase == ".xml" }
```

If you really just want a boolean :

```
require 'find'
Find.find("/var/data/").any?{|f| f=~/\.xml$/i }
```

Note that if `"/var/data/"` exists but there is no `.xml` file inside it, this method will be at least as slow as `Dir.glob`.

As far as I can tell :

```
Dir.glob("/var/data/**/*.xml"){|f| break f}
```

creates a complete array first before returning its first element.

## Bash-only

For a bash-only solution, you could use :

- [`compgen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195247/6419007)
- Shell [`find`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264351/6419007)

Comment: I'm afraid that `find` is not a solution for me.

Path pattern that I have to check is in fact entered by the user and later passed to `find` shell command.

The final effect that I want to achieve is to avoid `no such file or directory` error when executing `find` (from shell, not ruby `Find.find`)

Comment: Got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79301/test-if-there-are-files-matching-a-pattern-in-order-to-execute-a-script might help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash It looks like shell `find` might be the best option, followed by `compgen`.

Comment: Thank you, `compgen` works very well. It is not perfect, as it is bash-only solution, but fortunately it is available on all machines that I'm using.